# How to create a specialized a function template for a custom templated object?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

So I am not sure if this is possible but I want to have specialized function for a templated custom object.

I have custom objects:

```
template<unsigned N>
struct A {};

struct B {};
```

Now I am trying to define specialized functions to handle different structs. Specifically I want to create a function to handle objects of type A for any N. However, I am having trouble finding the correct syntax for this. The only way I have gotten this to work is by using explicit specialization.

```
// Default function handler
template<typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
    std::cout << "Default handler" << std::endl;
}

// This part will not compile, syntax is wrong
template<typename T<unsigned N>>
void foo(T<N> t)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized handler" << std::endl;
}

template<typename>
void foo(A<5> t)
{
    std::cout << "this is called properly when 5 is specified" << std::endl;
}
```

What would the correct syntax be for having a specialized function for all types of A objects?

Edit: For Clarity on why B is there, I am calling the function like so.

```
template<typename T>
class Caller
{
    public:
    Caller(T d): data(d) {}
    T data;

    void callFoo()
    {
        foo<T>(data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<5> t1;
    B t2;
    A<10> t3;
    Caller<A<5>> a(t1);
    Caller<B> b(t2);
    Caller<A<10>> a2(t3);

    a.callFoo(); // Calls explicit
    b.callFoo(); // Calls default
    a2.callFoo(); // need to call specialized function 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specialize, overload instead.  Function template specializations should be avoided if at all possible as they don't actually participate in overload resolution which can lead to some interesting results.  For your code, you can just add an overload like

```
template<unsigned N>
void foo(A<N> t)
{
    std::cout << "A<N> Handler" << std::endl;
}
```

And this overload will be preferred since the template is "more specialized"

Comment: Sorry I just edited my question to improve clarity. But, currently your solution calls the default handler.

Comment: @LT21j Is doing that because you use `foo<T>`.  99% of the time you shouldn't specify the template parameter and this is one of those.  In doing `foo<T>` you say call a template function with the parameter `T`.  Since my overload doesn't take a type but a value it will never be called.  `foo(data)` on the other hand will: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd5ea7dd6f141182

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically I want to create a function to handle objects of type A for any N.

You can write an overload like this:

```
template <unsigned N>
void foo(A<N> t);
```

This will not be a *specialization* of the earlier template. Partial specializations of function templates are not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand what is the relevance of `B` so maybe I misunderstand the question...

If you want a function template that you can pass an object of any instantiation of the template `A`, that would be:

```
#include <iostream> 

template<unsigned N>
struct A {};


template <unsigned N>
void foo(const A<N>&) { std::cout << N << '\n'; }

int main() 
{ 
    foo(A<3>());
}
```

prints :

```
3
```